# Умная форма в laravel 7 в шаблоне Blade(Form::select) & Controller

Tags: php, laravel, form, controller, blade

Добрый день уважаемые мастера своего дела!
Возникла задача сделать выпадающее меню которое открывало бы дополнительные опции, пример.

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputsKvantum">Выбор направления обучения:</label>
          {{ Form::select('inputsKvantum', ['Шахматы' => 'Шахматы', 'Энерджи' => 'Энерджи', 'Хай-Тек' => 'Хай-Тек', 'ИТ' => 'ИТ', 'Математика' => 'Математика', 'Нано' => 'Нано', 'Промробо' => 'Промробо', 'VR-AR' => 'VR-AR'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
          <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputsKvantum" placeholder="Хай-Тек"> -->
        </div>
```

Нужно чтобы при выборе направления(например) Шахматы были доступны преподаватели именно Шахмат

```
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="teacherName">Преподаватель: </label>
              {{ Form::open('teacherName', ['teacherName' => 'TimetableController@teacherName'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
          </div>
```

С Ларавель относительно не давно, по этому не знаю как это сделать ну и с php тоже, понимаю что должен быть один контроллер что связывает их всех в if конструкцию и обрабатывает сразу две формы, но как сделать не знаю, неделю уже пытаюсь много перечитал но ничего путного так и не пришло в голову.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Думаю без JS тут не обойтись и AJAX запросов. При изменении `select` с направлениями, отправляете запрос на сервер, для получения данных с преподавателями для нужного направления, на стороне сервера вы можете отрендерить нужные вам данные или же вернуть в формате json. После уже в html добавить `select` с преподавателями

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, попробую как вы сказали.